# How to make background with curves in bottom?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to know how I can make these curves even in the image?

[image]

Comment: please tell us your approach or show us the code you have and we can further assist you, please read [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `svg` for that.

```css
.background-img {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/12/10/19/fantasy-3077928_960_720.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

#bigHalfCircle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

#bigHalfCircle path {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="background-img">
  <svg id="bigHalfCircle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 100 C40 0 60 0 100 100 Z"></path>
  </svg>
</section>

<section class="background--color" style="background-color: #fff; height: 500px;">
</section>
```